# Linq AND searches

Tags: c#, linq

I have a array called searchWords, that is a dynamic array that stores peoples search words. I need to add an option for AND search. So the search will only retrieve items if both variables in searchWords contains for resultList. Now it is searchWords.Any. Will searchWords.All make this works?

```
 var resultList = from c in context.Category
     join q in context.Question on c.CategoryId equals q.CategoryId
     join qf in context.QuestionFilter on q.QuestionId equals qf.QuestionId
     join a in context.Answer on q.QuestionId equals a.QuestionId into QuestAnsw
     from a2 in QuestAnsw.DefaultIfEmpty()
     orderby c.SortOrder
     orderby q.SortOrder
     where qf.FilterId == filterKeyAsInt
     && q.Published == true
     && c.Published == true
     && q.CustomerId == customerId
     && (searchWords.Any(w => a2.Text.Contains(w))
     || searchWords.Any(w => c.Text.Contains(w))
     || searchWords.Any(w => q.Text.Contains(w)))
     select new { Category = c, Question = q };
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you want it to work. Can you describe how the multiple search words should match the multiple columns, i.e. what is needed for it to be considered a match?

Comment: Use two "where" clauses

Comment: so you want to show all the questions where the question or answer contains all the searchWords !!!

Comment: Thats correct Nikita

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if use **searchWords.All**, but i think **searchWords.Any** is more intuitive.

```
var resultList = from c in context.Category
     join q in context.Question on c.CategoryId equals q.CategoryId
     join qf in context.QuestionFilter on q.QuestionId equals qf.QuestionId
     join a in context.Answer on q.QuestionId equals a.QuestionId into QuestAnsw
     from a2 in QuestAnsw.DefaultIfEmpty()
     orderby c.SortOrder
     orderby q.SortOrder
     where qf.FilterId == filterKeyAsInt
     && q.Published == true
     && c.Published == true
     && q.CustomerId == customerId
     && !
     (
         searchWords.All(w => !a2.Text.Contains(w))
         && searchWords.All(w => !c.Text.Contains(w))
         && searchWords.All(w => !q.Text.Contains(w))
     )
     select new { Category = c, Question = q };
```

Comment: why are you using !contains ?

Comment: double negative for changing Any to All, you can see there is a not added before searchWords

Comment: oh, i mix sql and linq in the answer, then replace not to !

Comment: Thank you, and this solution will show all the questions where the question or answer contains all the searchWords?

Answer (score 0):

You can put multiple clauses inside an `All()`, e.g.

```
&& (searchWords.All(w =>
    a2.Text.Contains(w) &&
    c.Text.Contains(w) &&
    q.Text.Contains(w)))
...
```